# Objective-C - Position Object with CGPoint from another Method

Tags: objective-c

Hello i have got a question. I hope anybody could help me. I do not understand… I have a method returnPointFromArray where i have an array with values (e.g. 50.0, 100.0). Than i want to random it and then i want to use the CGPoint p in the Method drawObjectWithPoint to position my Object (object from another class) with the random value.

But the drawObjectWithPoint Method says always that the CGPoint p ist 0.0, 0,0 or he says "Use of undeclared identifier `p` or "instance variable hides…" .

I tried the same principle to test with int and this works.

I don´t know what i´m doing wrong.

It would be great if anybody could help me and explain what i´m doing wrong.

Thanks a lot.

```
.h
-(void)returnPointFromArray;
-(void)drawObjectWithPoint;


.m
-(void)returnPointFromArray
{
    NSArray *points = [];

    //Random for points

     NSUInteger *randomIndex = arc4random() % [points count];

     NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
     CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
}

-(void)drawObjectWithPoint
{
    Object *myObject [[Object alloc]init];
    CGPoint pNew = p;
    myObject.position = 
    [self addChild:myObject];
}
```

Comment: you have declared `p` in `-(void)returnPointFromArray` and you r trying to use it in `-(void)drawObjectWithPoint`. thats why its giving the `undeclared identifier p`

Comment: I also tried to declare it in the .h file, but this also don´t work!! Can somebody show me a way to solve the problem???

Comment: how did you declare it in **.h** file..? I have provided you the code below. please check that

Comment: If you mark someone's answer as correct I'm sure it'll help you in future

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:  **Edited**: (This is how yo declare in .h file)

**in .h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyClass : UIViewController {
    CGPoint p;
}
-(void)returnPointFromArray;
-(void)drawObjectWithPoint;
@end
```

**in .m file**

```
-(void)returnPointFromArray  {
    NSArray *points = [];

    //Random for points

     NSUInteger *randomIndex = arc4random() % [points count];

     NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
     p = [val CGPointValue]; // change here
}

-(void)drawObjectWithPoint  {
    Object *myObject [[Object alloc]init];
    CGPoint pNew = p;
    myObject.position = 
    [self addChild:myObject];
}
```

Comment: The method name "returnPointFromArray" implies that you are returning a value - you'd be better actually returning something & not bothering with the instance variable.

Comment: well it should return the value but the user2343538 doesnt want anything to be returned..

Answer (score 1):

assign value directly by method call

```
-(void)drawObjectWithPoint
{
    Object *myObject [[Object alloc]init];
    myObject.position = [self returnPointFromArray];
    [self addChild:myObject];
}

-(CGPoint)returnPointFromArray  {
    NSArray *points = [];

    //Random for points

     NSUInteger *randomIndex = arc4random() % [points count];

     NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
     return [val CGPointValue]; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry samfisher - just posted the same answer as you - wasn't there when I started :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just declared `CGPoint p;` in .h file. You declared it as locally(`returnPointFromArray` function) means its scope is local for that function only. check [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html)
 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your returnPointFromArray method returns void - just modify it -

```
-(CGPoint)returnPointFromArray
{
    // your code

    return p;
}
```

Then where you want to use p, just write

```
CGPoint pNew = [self returnPointFromArray];
```

obviously you'll have to add code which actually uses this value - your code doesn't do this at all -

```
myObject.position = pNew;
```